# No suitable conversion exists from to * exists

Tags: c++, class, data-structures, linked-list, switch-statement

I am using linked lists to manipulate a sorted list. However, in my function PutUser, I am getting an error when calling on another function to compare two users. I am not sure what to do or how to handle the error.

Here is my NodeUser struct (creates nodes for the linked list):

```
struct NodeUser { 
    User user;
    NodeUser* nextOnList;
};
```

I then have a function that is suppose to create a new node and put a user into the list

```
void SortedList::PutUser(User* user) {
    NodeUser* newNode; /
    NodeUser* previousPointer; 
    NodeUser* location; 
    bool moreToSearch;

    location = topOfList;
    previousPointer = NULL;
    moreToSearch = (location != NULL);

    while (moreToSearch) {
        switch (user->comparedTo(location->user)) {
        case GREATER:
            previousPointer = location;
            location = location->next;
            moreToSearch = (location != NULL);
            break;
        case LESS:
            moreToSearch = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    newNode = new NodeUser;
    newNode->user = user;

    if (previousPointer == NULL) {
        newNode->next = topOfList;
        topOfList = newNode;
    }
    else {
        newNode->next = location;
        previousPointer->next = newNode;
    }
    length++;
}
```

I am getting the error at (specifically location is underlined in red (error)):

```
switch (user->comparedTo(location->user))
```

How to fix the error at the switch?

Comment: Please don't vandalize your question.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to pass a `User` *object* where a `User*` *pointer* is expected.

There is no reason to pass a `User` object *by pointer* into `SortedUserType::PutUser()` or `User::comparedTo()`.  Pass it in *by reference* instead:

```cpp
class User {
public:
    ...
    RelationType comparedTo(const User &aUser) const;
    ...
};

void SortedUserType::PutUser(const User &user) {
    ...
    while (moreToSearch) {
        switch (user.comparedTo(location->user)) {
        ...
    }
    ...
    newNode = new NodeUser;
    newNode->user = user;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Your understanding is correct.  And you should prefer references instead of pointers for things that should not be NULL, as in this example.  Passing a pointer is the C way to pass an object around without making a copy of it. Passing a reference is the preferred C++ way (references don't exist in C), unless you actually need a pointer (because it can be NULL, or for compatibility with legacy C code).

Comment: Not surprising.  A LOT of instructors tend to teach with a "C within a C++ environment" type of approach, they don't teach *real* C++, unless they are focusing on fundamentals and not higher level C++ concepts (like references instead of pointers, using `std::list` instead of a manual linked list, `std::string` instead of `char[]`, etc).

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix would be to

```cpp
RelationType comparedTo(User const &aUser) const;
```

Or at least

```cpp
switch (user->comparedTo(&location->user))
```

Pointers should not be overused.

Comment: The code will then fail on `newNode->user = user;` trying to assign a `User*` to a `User`, so you would need to dereference the pointer: `newNode->user = *user;` "*Pointers should not be overused*" - agreed, in this case references would make more sense.